# Where is the Project Directory in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, directory, ms-project

Where is the project directory in microsoft visual studio C++? How can you add files so that in your line of code you can write **#include "myfile"**? Thanks...

Comment: you mean the one in your user document under visual studio\projects ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a Visual Studio project directory is a sub-directory of a solution directory. However, it doesn't need to be. E.g. you can add a project to multiple solutions.

For any given project, in the project settings the location of the project directory is available via the `$(ProjectDir)` macro expansion.

You can also use such macro expansions to access ordinary environment variables.

The difference between `#include "blah"` and `#include <blah>` is that the former adds a compiler-dependent additional search for the header, before (if that fails) doing the same search as the latter. With most (all?) modern compilers the additional search includes searching in the directory of the including file. Thus,

one way to add a file so that you can write just `#include "myfile"` in your code, is to place the file in the same directory as the including code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory containing your file to the include directories list:

> Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories